# $\mathsf{AC}_{\omega_1}$ and $L(\mathbb R)$

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Assume that the Axiom of Choice holds in $V$, the von Neumann universe. As [Andreas Blass explained](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656576/dependent-choice-and-l-mathbb-r), $\mathsf{DC}$ holds in $L(\mathbb R)$.

> Is this the case for $\mathsf{AC}_{\omega_1}$ too? That is, do we have $L(\mathbb R)\models \mathsf{AC}_{\omega_1}$?

(Here $\mathsf{AC}_{\omega_1}$ stands for the Axiom of Choice for families of cardinality $\omega_1$.)

It seems to me that the answer is yes, as $\mathsf{AC}_{\omega_1}$ involves only bounded quantifiers. Is this right?

Comment: In my answer that you linked to, the next-to-last sentence uses that any $\omega$-sequence of reals can be coded (in an absolute way) by a single real. That breaks down if you want to code an $\omega_1$-sequence of reals. Let me also mention a theorem that I think is due to Shelah (maybe independently to Raisonnier): The existence of an $\omega_1$-sequence of distinct reals implies the existence of a set of reals that is not Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

For example in Solovay's model, we start with $L$ and an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, and then consider $L(\Bbb R)$ in $L[G]$, where $G$ is $L$-generic for collapsing $\kappa$ to be $\omega_1$.

In this model there is no set of size $\aleph_1$ of reals, but there is always a surjection from $\Bbb R$ onto $\omega_1$. So $\sf AC_{\omega_1}$ must fail.

Other examples come from the natural models of $\sf AD$, which of course also disproves $\sf AC_{\omega_1}$. I have a sneaky suspicion that the large cardinal is necessary here, but I don't see any solution one way or another.

I will note that the "standard attempt" of adding $\omega_1$ Cohen reals and looking at $L(\Bbb R)$ will satisfy $\sf AC_{WO}$, that is choice from families which can be well-ordered, so in particular $\sf AC_{\omega_1}$ (this also gives an alternative proof of $\sf DC$).